# Dependent Bead Drawing

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am answering the same question as this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/485190/dependent-bead-draw

*"There are 5 black beads and 5 white beads in your pocket. You pull the beads out of your pocket one at a time, at random and without replacement. What is the probability that the third bead drawn from your pocket is the same color as the first?"*

But I want to come up with a combinatoric explanation:
I can find the first scenario in which all are the same color combinatorically

$ P(\text{All three same color}) = P(SS) = \frac{4}{9} * \frac{3}{8}
$

$ P(\text{All three same color}) = \frac{\binom{2}{1} * \binom{5}{3}}{\binom{10}{3}}
$

But when I try this for the second scenario where we get a different colored middle I'm just slightly off from the right answer

$ P(\text{Middle different}) = P(SDS) = \frac{5}{9} * \frac{4}{8} 
$

$ P(\text{Middle different}) = \frac{\binom{2}{1} * (\binom{5}{2} + \binom{5}{1})}{\binom{10}{3}}
$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are treating all of the beads as different, but you are disregarding order.

Order matters because it isn't enough to simply choose three beads, you have to place them so that they are in a valid order, for example $BW\!B$ works while $BWW$ doesn't.

Thus the probability is
$$\frac{10\cdot5\cdot4}{10\cdot9\cdot8}=\frac59\cdot\frac48.$$

Your first calculation works because all the colors will be the same, which gets rid of the complications I have previously described.

Comment: Oh, so because combinations don't consider order, it's impossible to answer in terms of some n choose k setup?

Comment: Yes, except in some special cases where everything is the same or the order doesn't matter for some reason (for example your first calculation).